# Building a component - database vendor neutral

Tags: extensions

Now that Joomla supports multiple database platforms how does an extension check which database the user is deploying on and whether your extension will work with it?

How do create platform specific install/uninstall scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Script file**

```
<!-- Runs on install/uninstall/update; New in 2.5 -->
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

In script file you can detect used driver:

Joomla 2.5

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication(); 
$dbtype = $app->getCfg('dbtype');
```

Joomla 3

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication(); 
$dbtype = $app->get('dbtype');
```

Depending on that, execute different code.

Let's say you only support `mysql`. Detect Joomla! database type on `preflight` and check if it matches. If not, deny install.

> At this point you could conceivably prevent the installation by calling the abort mechanism from the parent or prepare anything ahead of the file copy and database changes occurring.
>
> Source: https://docs.joomla.org/Extension_Installer/Installer_Hooks

```
/**
 * Called before any type of action
 *
 * @param   string  $route  Which action is happening (install|uninstall|discover_install|update)
 * @param   JAdapterInstance  $adapter  The object responsible for running this script
 *
 * @return  boolean  True on success
 */
public function preflight($route, JAdapterInstance $adapter){
    
    $app = JFactory::getApplication(); 
    $dbtype = $app->get('dbtype');

    if($dbtype != 'mysql'){
        JError::raiseWarning(null, 'This component dosen\'t support '.$dbtype.' database driver.');

        // Prevent install
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Install / uninstall SQL files**

You can create different files for different database drivers. Notice the `driver` attribute on `file` tag.

```
<install> <!-- Runs on install -->
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</install>
<uninstall> <!-- Runs on uninstall -->
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</uninstall>
```

See [Joomla! docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#SQL).

**Update SQL files**

Same on update sql files, you can set `type` attribute for every `schemapath`.

```
<update> <!-- Runs on update; New since J2.5 -->
    <schemas>
        <schemapath type="mysql">sql/updates/mysql</schemapath>
        <schemapath type="sqlsrv">sql/updates/sqlsrv</schemapath>
    </schemas>
</update>
```

See [Joomla! docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Update_of_the_SQL_schema).

**Support**

See [supported storage connectors](https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase#Supported_Storage_Connectors).